# How to simplify function to find out if a string contains coordinates that describe polygon?

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
points = "34.09352 -118.27483, 34.0914 -118.2758, 34.082 -118.2782, 34.0937 -118.2769, 34.0933 -118.2748"
```

`points` is a string that contains coordinate values (latitude & longitude) separated by commas.

I want to check that this string contains only integers or float values and that the first coordinate equals the last.

I have the following code for that:

```
def validate_points(points):
   coordinates = points.split(',')

   for point in coordinates:
      latlon = point.split(' ')

      latitude = latlon[0]
      longitude = latlon[1]
      if not is_number(latitude) or not is_number(longitude):
         raise WrongRequestDataError("Please, specify the correct type of points value. It must be a numeric value")

   first = coordinates[0]
   last = coordinates[len(coordinates) - 1]
   if first != last:
        raise WrongRequestDataError("Incorrect points format, the first point must be equal to last")

def is_number(s):
   try:
     if float(s) or int(s):
        return True
   except ValueError:
        return False
```

Is there any way to simplify or speed up this code?

Comment: LGTM, you could write `coordinates[-1]` instead of `coordinates[len(coordinates)-1]`, though.

Comment: You could remove line 12-15 to outside of the for loop.

Comment: remember *if it can `int(..)` it can `float(..)` too*. So the `if float(s) or int(s)` can be reduced to `if float(s)`

Comment: FYI a polygon is not just a sequence of points. For example two points, expressed as `"Ax Ay, Bx By, Ax, Ay"` is not a polygon.  And if any of the segments intersect then it is not a polygon.

Comment: @ipetr Note that your `is_number` function will return `None` for `s = '0'` for example. Because `not None` evaluates to `True`, strings like `'0'` are considered not to be numbers from your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input almost looks like a [WKT polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).

Using the [`shapely`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) package, you could simply try to parse the points as WKT and see what happens, according to Python's ["Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360880/6419007) principle:

```
# pip install shapely
from shapely import wkt

def is_well_defined_polygon(points):
    try:
        wkt.loads("POLYGON((%s))" % points)
        return True
    except:
        return False

points = "34.09352 -118.27483, 34.0914 -118.2758, 34.082 -118.2782, 34.0937 -118.2769, 34.0933 -118.2748, 34.09352 -118.27483"

print(is_well_defined_polygon(points))
# True
print(is_well_defined_polygon("1 2, 3 4"))
# IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
# False
print(is_well_defined_polygon("a b c d"))
# ParseException: Expected number but encountered word: 'a'
# False
```

Comment: you dropped the bomb on the this thread. It's not fun playing with you guys.. +1 xD

Answer (score 0):

Here are some improvements. You can speed up is_number function a bit, and use `coordinates[-1]` instead of `coordinates[len(coordinates)-1]. You also don't necessarily need to define all those variables:

```
def validate_points(points):
   coordinates = points.split(',')

   for point in coordinates:
       latitude, longitude = point.split(' ', 1)

       if not is_number(latitude) or not is_number(longitude):
          raise WrongRequestDataError("Please, specify the correct type of points value. It must be a numeric value")

   if coordinates[0] != coordinates[- 1]:
       raise WrongRequestDataError("Incorrect points format, the first point must be equal to last")
def is_number(s):
   try:
        return (float(s) or int(s) or True)
   except ValueError:
       return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor things:

- Use `coordinates[-1]` instead of `coordinates[len(coordinates)-1]`
- Use `latitude, longitude = point.split(' ', 1)`. This will cause cases like `3.41 47.11 foobar` to be invalid.
- Do you really need `latitude` and `longitude` to be strings? You probably want the float/int value, so `is_number` should be something like

  ```
  def conv_number(s):
      try:
          return float(s)
      except ValueError:
          try:
              return int(s)
          except ValueError:
              raise WrongRequestDataError(s)
  ```

I especially like the fact that you do not use `isinstance` to check for float/int: In python, you should always be able to pass an arbitrary object that acts like a `int` or `float` if asked to do so.

Comment: How is `isinstance` relevant for checking if a string is a valid number? Also we're not having "arbitrary" objects here but _strings_. Also I can't think of any case where `float` would raise but `int` doesn't (provided you don't change the `base` argument).

Comment: people come up with `isinstance` all the time when dealing with type conversion. Prime example is taking an argument and `if not isinstance(foobar, str): raise TypeError` instead of just `str(foobar)`.

Comment: The question is not about type conversions. Also the question deals with the clearly defined API of the Python standard library, so I don't see how you expect something else to be returned from `str.split`. I.m.o. mentioning `isinstance` here is off the mark and just confuses the reader. Also could you clarify when you expect `float` to raise but similarly `int` not?

Comment: You, sir, win one internets.

Answer (score 0):

That is how I would do it:

```
points = "34.09352 -118.27483, 34.0914 -118.2758, 34.082 -118.2782, 34.0937 -118.2769, 34.0933 -118.2748"


def validate_points(points):
    separate = points.split(',')

    try:
        [float(y) for x in separate for y in x.split()]
    except ValueError:
        return False

    return separate[0] == separate[-1]

print(validate_points(points))  # False
```

---

If you actually want to raise an Error you can modify\simplify the code as follows:

```
def validate_points(points):
    separate = points.split(',')
    [float(y) for x in separate for y in x.split()]  # orphan list-comprehension
    if not separate[0] == separate[-1]:
        raise ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks, but the algorithm doesn't need to return something. It's just throw an exception in case of invalid data

Comment: What about `return False` in the `except` branch? This saves you the additional `else` branch and the `and` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

my solution with using **Regex named group** to filter data:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re


class WrongRequestDataError(Exception):
    pass

def position_equal(pos1, pos2):
    # retrun pos1 == pos2 # simple compare
    accuracy = 0.005
    return (
        abs(float(pos1['latitude']) - float(pos2['latitude'])) <= accuracy and
        abs(float(pos1['longitude']) - float(pos2['longitude'])) <= accuracy
    )

test_str = "34.09352 -118.27483, 34.0914 -118.2758, 34.082 -118.2782, 34.0937 -118.2769, 34.0933 -118.2748"

regex = r"(?P<position>(?P<latitude>\-?\d+(\.\d+)?) (?P<longitude>\-?\d+(\.\d+)?))"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE)

matched = []
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matched.append({
        'latitude': match.group('latitude'),
        'longitude': match.group('longitude'),
    })

matched_count = len(matched)
if matched_count != test_str.count(',') + 1:
    raise WrongRequestDataError("Please, specify the correct type of points value. It must be a numeric value")
else:
    if matched_count > 1:
        if not position_equal(matched[0], matched[-1]):
            raise WrongRequestDataError("Incorrect points format, the first point must be equal to last")
```

You can modify the accuracy's value in position_equal function to change the accuracy when compare first and last position.

You can test or debug the regex at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/tYYJXN/1/